# Unable to launch UiAutomatorViewer on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: java

I'm trying to launch UiAutomatorViewer but I've got the following error:

```
  -Djava.ext.dirs=/home/user/Workspace/android-sdk-linux/tools/lib/x86_64:
 /home/user/Workspace/android-sdk-linux/tools/lib is not supported.
 Use -classpath instead. Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
 Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

My java version is `openjdk version "9-internal"`

Answer (score 0):

Fixed,I downgraded openjdk from 9 to 8

Comment: Can you please explain how you downgraded?

Comment: if remember well i used sudo update-alternatives --config java